# Improving ParticleSystem performance in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm running a simulation of asteroids that move in orbits around our solar system.  You can see an initial implementation [here](http://asterank.com/3d/).

I converted the entire set of orbiting objects to a single ParticleSystem and I can run 10,000 orbits at 60fps on my home machine (about 30fps on my laptop).  15-20k brings my machine down to 30fps.

I am running a web worker to compute a new list of positions, and then I update positions for each object in the main thread like so:

```
    for (var j=0; j < positions.length; j++) {
      myobjects[j].MoveParticleToPosition(positions[j]);
    }
    particle_geometry.__dirtyVertices = true;
```

MoveParticleToPosition:

```
  var vertex_particle = this.particle_geometry.vertices[this.vertex_pos];
  vertex_particle.x = pos[0];
  vertex_particle.y = pos[1];
  vertex_particle.z = pos[2];
```

My question is: how can I improve performance from here?

For example, is there a quicker way to update the geometry vertices?  Are there optimizations I can apply to a ParticleSystem?  Is it possible to update vertices from within a web worker?

Comment: __dirty flags are no longer supported. You might as well update to the current version of three.js and have a look at the wiki: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wound up using two other techniques to improve performance in addition to switching to a ParticleSystem.  None of them are specific to Three.js.  They involved using web workers and splitting loops in chunks with `setTimeout` to give Three.js a chance to update the rendering.

I wrote a blog post with more technical details [here](http://ianww.com/blog/programming/optimizing-three-js-performance-simulating-tens-of-thousands-of-independent-moving-objects/).